# Angular 8 - Why client makes multiple API calls to back-end

Tags: c#, json, angular, rest, client

I have a classic client application with API calls to the server to make operations on DB. But for some reason, every client method in service makes two calls to my controller when I need just once.

What's the reason, why and how I could fix it? Moreover, the second call comes also if the back-end didn't return anything yet but still performing operation.

That's some code example:

Method calls the service:

```
export class TestingComponent implements OnInit {

results: any;

constructor(
private testingservice: TestingService) { }

ngOnInit() {
let test = true;
this.startingMethod(test);
 }

startingMethod(test) {
    this.testingservice.getData(test).subscribe( data => {
        this.results = data;
  })};
}
```

Service method:

```
export class TestingService{

constructor(private configService: ConfigService, private http: HttpClient) { }

getData(test: boolean): Observable<any> {

let urlc = this.configService.getCurrentEndpoints();
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.set('test', test);
return this.http.get<any>(`${urlc.baseUrl}${urlc.getdata}`, {'params': params });
}
}
```

I hope was clear enough, but if I don't freely ask me more details. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you have any interceptors?

Comment: Please open browser console and check if the first call is an OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug from the browsers, they sends the second request to get the favicon of the page, and since they don't have it, it just brings anything.

This is a link for the Chrome bug.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402

Firefox, and most other browsers, also send out a request for a favicon when they first connect, but cache the result i.e. if there isn't a favicon returned first time, they don't keep trying - which is why you're only seeing a single request from Firefox. It seems Chrome is unfortunately a little too persistent with its favicon requestiness.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There may be two reasons for this case:
As you mentioned that there are two calls for BE, maybe one of them is preflight request.
You can read about this here: https://livebook.manning.com/book/cors-in-action/chapter-4/

The second reason may be multiple subscriptions:

You can change the calling of service call like:

```
startingMethod(test) {
    this.testingservice.getData(test).toPromise().then( data => {
        this.results = data;
  })}
```

or you can use a subscription object like:

```
subscription = new Subscription();

startingMethod(test) {
this.subscription.add(
    this.testingservice.getData(test).subscribe( data => {
        this.results = data;
  }));
}

ngOnDestroy(){
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Moreover, the second call comes also if the back-end didn't return anything yet but still performing the operation.

I suspect that you are refering to the `OPTIONS` request. That is a CORS preflight request that is generated by the browser itself which is totally normal.

`OPTIONS` requests are what we call pre-flight requests in `Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)`.

They are necessary when you're making requests across different origins in specific situations.